# Same url for overloaded controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my web api application, I want to enable clients to make requests, using the same path, but pass different type of parameters.

For example:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [HttpDelete]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete2(Guid id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete3(string id) {..}

}
```

I want the url for each method to be similar, for example:

```
api/MyController/1
api/MyController/abc etc..
```

Is this possible? Iv'e tried alot of combinations with `ActionName` attribute and Routing configuration, but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks

Comment: If they are all doing the same thing, I suggest creating a custom class (object) to hold each of these (nullable) properties, and using 1 route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for this. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("MyController")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("delete/{id:int}")]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("delete/{id:guid}")]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete2(Guid id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("delete/{id:alpha}")]
   public IHttpActionResult       Delete3(string id) {..}

}
```

If you do this then the request url will be:

```
http://yoursever/mycontroller/delete/123
http://yoursever/mycontroller/delete/abc
http://yoursever/mycontroller/delete/91c74f8f-d981-4ee1-ba36-3e9416bba202
```

Comment: Is this one a valid case : *api/MyController/"abc"* ??

Comment: You don't need put the string in quotes

Comment: yes thats why I am confused about, seems that OP wants to differentiate `string` and `int` by *api/MyController/"1"* and *api/MyController/1* ....

Comment: @SamGhatak in that case you can add the `Order` for each route to determine priority. (It's in the link I put in the question). Thank you for mentioning that BTW.

Comment: Also, if you use `{id:alpha}` number will not be matched and your API will return a 404 since it can't find a matching route.

Comment: That's what I thought, calling api with "1" to indicate 1 as a string is not the way....

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a `Route` with different parameter types for each of your methods:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("{id:int}", Order = 1)]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("{id:guid}", Order = 2)]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete2(Guid id) {..}

   [HttpDelete]
   [Route("{id}", Order = 3)]
   public IHttpActionResult Delete3(string id) {..}

}
```

Of course you have to [enable attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) if you haven't already.
The `Order` property for the `Route` attribute ensures that the route templates are checked in the correct order so that an `int` value will not match the string route.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Try setting the route as a `decoration`.

example:

```
        [Route("DeleteThis/{id}")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteThis(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [Route("NowDeleteThis/{name}")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteThis(string name)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Won't that change the URL?

Comment: Yes, however it wont change the method name.

Comment: What's up with the forward slash at the end of the route?